# Does measuring the exact position of a ball destroy the ball

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

If you have a macroscopic ball (say, a tennis ball) and you (hypothetically) try to measure the exact position of the center of that ball by measuring the exact positions of the atoms making up the ball, will this measurement destroy the ball (i.e. is there a point where, as a result of the uncertainty principle, the more accurately you measure the position of each of the atoms, the more likely the atoms are to scatter off in some random direction, destroying the ball)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes? The more accurate you measure, the higher the frequency / smaller the wavelength of the measuring equipment needs to be, eventually vaporizing the ball due to the high amount of energy contained in the high frequency of the measuring wave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you really have to measure each atom individually. So it is not very different from measuring a single atom. By measuring atom 1 of the ball, this atom is scattered of due to its momentum uncertainty. By measuring atom 2 this is scattered off too, and so on.

However, the centre of mass of a macroscopic object obeys a free Schrödinger equation (as long as there are no external fields). So any measurement of the centre-of-masss position will only give you a high uncertainty of the centre-of-mass momentum. But it won't have any influence on the relative motion of the atoms of your ball. So by measuring your balls centre you might give the ball a velocity but it will still be intact.